# Do we need individual JNDI for each of the 2 VMs that are connecting to single database

Tags: jdbc, jndi

I am new to the current project that I am working on.
We have a Java web-app running on weblogic where we have 2 VMs, one active and the other passive, each in different AZs.
Both the VMs connect to the same Database.
The devops person is asking me the following question.

> We have a JNDI URL in the properties file which connects to the
> database from VM1 (in AZ1). We need to specify another JNDI URL in the
> same properties file to connect to the same database from VM2 (in AZ2)
> to the same database. Both VMs have the same war file

Is such a scenario possible? Any suggestions???